# Gradle android-library build fails. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to build my android library project, which contains sub test project. Command to build: **gradle clean connectedCheck**
After task :dexTest I got error:

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/json/simple/ItemList;
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/commons/lang3/CharRange$1;

Command **gradle clean build** ends successful. So my problem is that i can't run my tests. When i change plugin, in my build.gradle file, from 'android-library' to 'android' everything works fine.

Also, i'm added --info param and got this, before error

command: /home/username/adt-bundle/sdk/build-tools/18.1.1/dx --dex --output /home/username/android/build/libs/android-test.dex /home/username/android/build/classes/test /home/username/android/build/dependency-cache/test /home/username/android/libs/json_simple.jar /home/username/android/build/bundles/debug/classes.jar /home/username/android/build/bundles/debug/libs/json_simple.jar /home/username/android/libs/android-support-v4.jar /home/username/android/build/bundles/debug/libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar /home/username/android/build/bundles/debug/libs/android-support-v4.jar /home/username/android/libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar

What was that? Why it uses libraries from folder build/bundles/debug/libs/? This is the reason why I had error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException but why gradle takes libraries from that dir i don't understand.

Here my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
        testPackageName "ua.cooperok.stringcalc.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile file('AndroidManifest.xml')
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        instrumentTest {
            manifest.srcFile file('tests/AndroidManifest.xml')
            java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['tests/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['tests/assets']
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

Maybe it's a bug in android-library plugin?

Comment: Well, your ```gradle build``` was successful because ```dexTest``` didn't get called during that task at all.

Comment: Can you show all the jar file names in your ```libs``` folder?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this? I saw your comment on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61429. I encountered the same error and getting stuck.

Comment: No I didn't solve it yet. My libs folder contains 3 jar files you can find them in question, they begin with path /home/username/android/libs/.  
I have only one solution but it's clearly no good. To run tests i'm change plugin to android and compile library like app, if tests were good, i'm changing back plugin to android-library.

Comment: That sounds unhandy actually. Have you tried [this #8](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61429#c8)? It just worked for me.

Comment: As I understand he ran gradle from his tests directory, not from app. I can't run gradle from another directroy, because I'm using Jenkins to automate builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now problem is no longer relevant. In build tools from version 0.7.2 it is fixed.
Piece of updates from [tech doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)
- Solve issue with local jar when testing library projects.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know exact answer to the question, my colleagues from JetBrains supporting gradle in IntelliJ IDEA advised to ask the question at https://code.google.com/p/android/ because it's clearly an issue (and may be a bug) in Google Android Gradle Plugin for Eclipse, given that you work in Eclipse, as far as I recall from our conversation.

Comment: Thank you for advise. Also i'm running gradle in linux shell, but not within Eclipse